# Add a sub-header to a form in tabbed navigation in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access

I created a tabbed navigation form. The navigation form has a header that shows up across all forms. Two of the forms also have their own headers that show just on those forms. One of the forms does not. I would like it to as well, but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried clicking on the "Title" option under "Header/Footer" in the form design, but that just takes me to the navigation title.

The picture shows what I mean by a sub-header.

[image]

Comment: I assume the picture you have posted is what you want, can you also post the picture of what you have currently?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you just want to add in a Header onto a subform.  To do this put the form into design view.  Make sure you have "Clicked into" the sub form you want to have the header, then right click the background and select  `Form Header/Footer`. If I have misunderstood the question please let me know.